# How to connect labeled data in Azure Machine Learning Studio/Data Labeling to Power BI?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to connect already labeled dataset in **Azure ML Studio** in **Data Labeling** to **PowerBI**. I would like to see the progress of labeling or the result of labeled data without exporting it manually and connecting the exported files one by one.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow these steps

**Step 1:** First Create a Workspace and Launching Machine Learning Studio

**Step 2:** Go to Machine Learning Studio and create model,
Refer this [Doc](https://app.pluralsight.com/guides/getting-started-with-azure-ml-studio/) for more information

**Step 3:** Deploy the Web Service

After customizing the web service output, you are ready to deploy it. Click the Deploy Web Service icon at the bottom. After the deployment is finished, you will see the following output with web service properties as shown below
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HElEN.png)

Copy the API key as shown above link and save it. This will be a different API key for your Azure account.

**Step 4:** Test the Web Service

Test the web service refer this [link](https://app.pluralsight.com/guides/publish-machine-learning-models-in-azure-machine-learning-studio#module-testthewebservice) for more information

**Step 5** Connect power bi with azure Machine learning

•   Open power bi login with same account were you create the Azure model

•    Import Data into Data Flow you need to save and store the data ( it will takes some time).

•   To see the  data and prediction result in Power BI desktop, first open it then sign into premium account, click on the get data and choose the Data flow connector.

•   you able to see all data flow you have, choose the related data flow and the prediction results

•   Select Get Data and go to power bi dataflow Then load it into Power BI desktop to see the result

•   Need more information about power bi connection refer this [Link](https://radacad.com/ai-in-dataflow-power-bi-webservice-auto-azure-ml-part2)

Comment: Hi, I know you can connect Azure Machine Learning Studio, but I need specifically .csv from Data Labeling section, look there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-image-labeling-projects

Comment: Hi @rchlvk, you will get .CSV File create pipeline in Machine Learning Studio and Add the Convert to CSV component to your pipeline and You can find this component in the **Data Transformation group** in the **designer**. Connect it to a dataset. Submit the pipeline

Comment: Hi, do you know by any chance how to export all files at once from Data Labeling in Designer?